# Failed to send certificate after upgrading to latest windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, certificate, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows Phone App, built for 8.1, and one of the tasks was a client-server certificate scenario. My app worked fine, I could send the client certificate and login to the server. However after upgrading to windows 8.10.14xxxx that was not possible. I took wireshark traces and it seems that the certificate is never send. 
The content length of the message is 0.

I use `HttpClient.SendAsync` (await) and `HttpBaseProtocolFilter` to enter the certificate. It worked perfect before the upgrade.

Any idea? Is something broken?

First I am installing the pfx

```
async private void btnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Install the self signed client cert to the user certificate store

    string CACertificate = null;
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///certificates/test.pfx");
        var file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
        using (DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
            // convert to Base64 for using with ImportPfx
            CACertificate = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
        await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
            CACertificate,
            "xxxxx",
            ExportOption.Exportable,
            KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
            InstallOptions.None,
            "ClientCert1");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //;
    }
}
```

Then I am calling the service

```
string serviceURL = "https://my.web.services";
Certificate cert = null;

CertificateQuery query = new CertificateQuery();
query.FriendlyName = "ClientCert1";
IReadOnlyCollection<Certificate> certs = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(query);

HttpBaseProtocolFilter bpf = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
//if you install the CA you don't need to ignore the ServerCertificate Errors
//bpf.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);

if (certs.Count > 0)
{
    cert = certs.ElementAt(0);
    bpf.ClientCertificate = cert;
}

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(bpf);
try
{

    var response = await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(new Uri(serviceURL));
    //take data
}
catch (Exception ex)
{              
    //0x80072F0D 
}
```

I am always taking an excepting (`0x80072F0D`) when running in `8.10.14xxxx` windows phone. My code worked before the update, now I am always taking this return code. The certificate is loaded in httpClient. When I stop the app with the debugger it seems that the certificate is there, however the `0x800072F0D` probably means that the certificate is not sent???

There is an intermediate certificate authority in the scenario. That certificate is included in the pfx. Do I need to install this somehow?

Comment: Do you have a repro?

Comment: @kiewic do you know the issue? I can share some source code.

Comment: Yes, I can take a look. You can put repro on GitHub or anywhere else.

Comment: any exception you got? TaskCanceledException or anyhting else?

Comment: sorry for not responding earlier. source code is now on the question body.

Comment: could it be this one??? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2015/03/20/how-to-use-a-shared-user-certificate-for-https-authentication-in-an-enterprise-application.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have already put the client certificate in app certificate store. 
If not then do these:
1) Download the PFX file.
 
2) Install certificate in the App's certificate store by following

```
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(certString, "Your_PFX_Password", ExportOption.Exportable, KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent, InstallOptions.None, friendlyName);
```

3) Check for the certificate in certificate store.

```
CertificateQuery certQuery = new CertificateQuery();
certQuery.FriendlyName = friendlyName;
IReadOnlyList<Certificate> certs = await CertificateStores.FindAllAsync(certQuery);
```

The `certs[0]` should have the certificate that you need.

4) Now, to attach the certificate to HTTP request

```
HttpBaseProtocolFilter protolFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
protolFilter.ClientCertificate = certs[0] //from previous step
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(protolFilter)
```

PS : You should not use `System.Net.htpp.HttpClient`. Instead of that you should use `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`.

Comment: No it does not work. This seems to be the correct procedure, I am already calling those lines (see my code above) however after  installing windows phone 8.1 update these lines do not work.

Comment: Which device are you using? One suggestion is, do a hard reset to your device and then try. And your issue is bit strange.

Comment: it is a Nokia Lumia 925. I don't think that hard reset resolves something.